# Make web service not accessible by browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms

I wrote a web service because I wanted my javascript to access methods in it throughout the website using ajax. I'm new to this. However I just realised that the asmx is accessible via browser and it shows a test page and xml output of data from the methods. is there a way to disable this UI for the web service? I only want it to return data to javascript methods when they are called.

Comment: No. If you expose a service via a URL, any client on the internet can access it. You can't *ever* tell for sure what's on the other end of an HTTP request. If you need a secured service, protect it behind some sort of authenticated session mechanism.

Comment: The "test" page you speak of is quite normal. Web services are exposed with a WSDL (Web Service Description Language) document and that is the document you are seeing. It is what tells clients what is available and how to call the methods.

Comment: well you can send headers and check on the server for them, but anyone can spoof headers

Comment: @ZillyFlix Have you solve your problem ? Can you accept an answer if one of them help you pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of .NET Web Services you're using, but you can disable the Web Service Help Page, which is typically only available locally anyway.  It may also disable the WSDL generation too.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tyf2t8t(v=vs.100).aspx or https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/how-to-disable-modify-the-default-test-pages-for-asmx-web-services.786001/

If you also want to prevent others from accessing your web service in general, you have to look at authentication techniques too.

Comment: Thank you. For now I have only exposed data that are anyway public. I'm generating GUID for each user and serving data for those users only. So I guess it's fine because I keep the GUID on the server and never expose to the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript accesses your webservice the same way you do with your browser. Close your service from your browser, you close it for your javascript.

Basically, you are saying you made a door in your house because you want to be able to get in (makes total sense!) but now you are worried because everybody can see the door (you could have thought of htat earlier!) and use it (that is your real problem!).
So what do you do? You put a lock on the door.

That doesn't make the door invisible, but it keeps the wrong people out.

You want to do the same with your web service: implement authentication / authorisation.

On a side note: it is 2017. I didn't even know people still used .asmx. Have a look at WCF, it more or less replaced the old asmx web services back in 2010 or so...

Comment: I learned  .NET recently by interning at a company who were working with legacy systems built with webforms.   So I learned the old ways and now I understand that I keep on using old technology. Gotta learn WCF and move on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. Your asmx should not display any sensitive data. If it does you have a design problem.

The XML data you're probably seeing is the WSDL. This is not a bad thing, in fact it is what allows consumers to know how your WebService is structured. For more information about about this you can see [this apge](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)